# Malware detection when installing tor browser

Tags: security

maybe its wrong here, if so, i´m sorry.
I tried to install the very first time tor browser for windows german version: torbrowser-install-7.0.4_de
from your website https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

When I checked this file by uploading to [www.virustotal.com](https://virustotal.com/#/home/upload) **I got 2 malware warnings:**

malware (ai score=18)

Malware.Heuristic!ET#99% (rdm+)

?

Thank You

Comment: Additionally to the answer below: if you scan it today, they say it is clean: https://virustotal.com/#/url/34efd36ac8d0b365b14ce93f82637f55b9731678b796cad1ccfbc43f8d50caa5/detection

Answer (score 2):

These are false positives. VirusTotal detects ["Hello World" programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) as [malicious](https://twitter.com/zerosum0x0/status/895648493422878720) and often detects [real malware as clean](https://twitter.com/hanno/status/468388548740403200).

[Anti-virus is not a good option](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/guide.md#anti-virus) if you have real anonymity or privacy requirements.